# BC30205 End of statement expected in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm having issues with VB.net.

I'm trying to make a file pumper for myself, but I'm not really having much luck with it. upon typing a whole line of code, I eventually stumble upon the error of "BC30205 End of statement expected". I know this error has been asked here before, but my code is different.. I guess...Thhe specific line that gives me an error is:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load        rbtnMegaByte.Checked = True
```

Visual Studio recommends me to delete both "System" in the code and keep it as "Object" and "EventArgs" but upon listening to Visual Studio I still have the "End of statement expected" error.

I'm not really the best at this, so sorry if this is a really easy mistake.

Answer (score 1):

That one line of code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load        rbtnMegaByte.Checked = True
```

Should be two lines:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load        
    rbtnMegaByte.Checked = True
```

I guess you have copied and pasted this from somewhere and it hasn't preserved the carriage returns?

You will also need `End Sub` further down but I assume that you have that already? So your subroutine should look like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load        
    rbtnMegaByte.Checked = True
    'Any other code here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This error may raised if you forget to close any block, check your blocks i.e check **end if** for any if or check **end sub** for sub etc. it would be better if you share some more code of that module